# USB cam with raspberry pi 3: achieving maximum FPS

Tags: video, webcam

I am using a ub camera with raspberry pi. When I run v4l2-ctl --list-formats-xext, I get the max FPS is 15 with resolution of 2592x1944.

However when I run 
ffmpeg -t 5 -f v4l2 -framerate 15 -video_size 2592x1944 -i /dev/video0 1.avi
I get a maximum FPS of 3.

Could someone help me how I can make the cam work at max FPS?

Comment: Not necessarily. I could use anything which helps me record videos at high FPS at full resolution

Comment: So. raspivid is probably what you want

Comment: No. Raspvid is for raspicam. I am using a USB camera

Comment: @Jaromanda X, My apologies. I am very new to this and don't understand your suggestion fully. Could you please help me by elaborating? 

If I understand you rightly, what you suggest will help me capture it in mjpeg and then in post-processing I can decode it. Is this right?

Comment: 15 FPS is the limit of your video device. Encoding 15 FPS video at those dimensions would require a more powerful CPU or hardware accelerated encoding. Try lowering frame height and width.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to increase the FPS substantially with your current hardware. USB has significant CPU overhead, and encoding a video stream is CPU-intensive too.

You could either replace your webcam with a RPi camera module which saves you the USB overhead, get a webcam that does mjpg compression itself (eg [known good with octoprint](https://community.octoprint.org/t/usb-webcams-known-to-work-with-mjpg-streamer/21149), look for those that does not require '-y'), or connect your webcam to a faster computer capable of handling the load.